# Setting the albedo property of a material

Tags: c#, godot

I'm just trying to set the color of a material at runtime.  The C# docs are sparse.

```
MaterialOverride.Set("albedo_color", new Color(1f, 1f, 1f));
```

Comment: this answers your question: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be (tested):

```
((SpatialMaterial)MaterialOverride).AlbedoColor = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f);
```

You would get `NullReferenceException` if you let `SpatialMaterial` uninitialized. You would get a `InvalidCastException` if it isn't a `SpatialMaterial` (it could be `ShaderMaterial`).

It happens that `MaterialOverride` is defined as `Material`, and there are a few classes that extend (inherit from) `Material`. Namely:  `CanvasItemMaterial`, `ParticlesMaterial`, `ShaderMaterial`, and `SpatialMaterial`. *And, of course, `AlbedoColor` is a property of `SpatialMaterial`.*

So C# does not know which of these `MaterialOverride` actually is, which is why we cast. *There are other ways to cast in C#, see [Casting and type conversions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).*

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm glad I don't need to use strings to access properties.

I understand inheritance and casting but I'm still relatively new to the class structure of Godot.

Comment: @DezBoyle what extends what is in the documentation (the documentation page of each class says at the top what it extends and which build-in classes extend it). If you prefer a tree, you can find that too, see [Inheritance class tree](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/cpp/inheritance_class_tree.html). Regarding C# what it is really missing is examples (edit: ideally it show the members in language specific syntax too). But it is not hard to figure out.